# how to programatically update DMN rules in camunda tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dynamic, deployment, camunda

I am using a DMN to evaluate my inputs but the requirement is such that the rules will get added in future, and rules will be added by normal users. So my concern is how do I provide a logic to dynamically Update/Add rules in the DMN and update it in camunda tomcat. I went through the Deployment create and redeploy rest api but unable to solve my problem.

Comment: I made good experience with updating dmn through rest deployments ... could you please elaborate whhat your concrete problems were? Like this, the question is too broad.

Comment: I have a DMN table with almost 70 rules, now i am developing a utility for adding or updating those rules as per requirement, but the thing is I want a way to deploy the new and updated DMN file in the camunda tomcat. I read about the Rest api showing redeploy service, but I need more help on that how to exactly put the updated DMN file in tomcat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple curl post to deploy a dmn resource from the command line

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/create \
     -F deployment-name="<NAME>" -F table.dmn=@<FILE>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: is it also possible to send XML string rather then file Object, like I have used dmn-js to edit the DMN file and then I am using its saveXML function to get the updated XML data. So since now I have a XML string can i use that as the input to deployment/create rest api rather then saving that file locally and the uploading it again ? I am just trying to make the best. Thanks in advance